# cause for conflicts during patch apply

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand why is the most common reason for patch apply conflict. I can assume that it is mismatching context of a change, am I right? For example, I have the following patch:

```
diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index d220f35..176c71a 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ module.exports = function (grunt) {
                         src: ['index.less', '!**/components/**'],
                         dest: 'build/development/css',
                         ext: '.css',
-                        cleancss: true
+                        cleancss: false
                     }
                 ]
             },
```

With 3 lines of context above and 3 lines of context below the change. If, when git applies the patch the first context line instead of being like this:

```
src: ['index.less', '!**/components/**'],
```

is like this:

```
this_is_changed_context_line: ['index.less', '!**/components/**'],
```

a conflict occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the `patch` command. In general, it uses the line numbers to locate the correct portion of the target file to patch. If the target file doesn't match the given context, `patch` assumes the line numbers are wrong and starts searching for the given context elsewhere in the file. If *that* fails, it uses a given "fuzz factor" to start dropping lines from the start and end of the context to see if the reduced context can be used to find a match. Eventually, it finds somewhere where the given change can be applied, or it gives up.

Comment: thanks! so basically mismatching context is the main reason for patch fail? Also is it possible to apply a patch to the file other than specified in the patch?

Comment: It sounds like you have a very specific situtation in mind; perhaps you should put this detail in a new question.

Comment: right, here [it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523354/specify-to-which-file-a-patch-should-apply).