# Specify to which file a patch should apply

Tags: git

For example, I have the following git patch:

```
diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index d220f35..176c71a 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ module.exports = function (grunt) {
                         src: ['index.less', '!**/components/**'],
                         dest: 'build/development/css',
                         ext: '.css',
-                        cleancss: true
+                        cleancss: false
                     }
                 ]
             },
```

As you can see, it contains the path of the file onto which these changes should be applied (`Gruntfile.js`). Is there any way to apply this patch to the file other than the one specified in the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify directly which file is to be patched:

```
$ patch not-Gruntfile-but-close.js unset-cleancss.patch
```

Comment: thanks, should it be `git apply not-Gruntfile-but-close.js unset-cleancss.patch`?

Comment: Yes and no. It doesn't look to me that `git apply` allows you to specify which files to patch; it only uses what is in the patch file itself. On the other hand, if you don't need any of the other options to `git apply`, you should be able to use the `patch` program directly to apply the patch.

Comment: thanks, does this `patch` program have anything to do with `git`? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: `man patch`. It's a program that's been around for a long time; I am not sure if `git apply` uses `patch` under the hood, or just implements the same algorithm.